# How to create 3D structure (artificial porous medium) randomly packed with spheres with varying radius

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, 3d, geometry

I want to create a 3D structure (cylinder or cube) for an ideal porous medium randomly packed by spheres:

[image: img] with a different radius.

I also want to save 2D slices of the image from the created 3D structure or visualise the internal structure.

Comment: what have you tried? where is the problem? What is the question? I see none ... You also did not share any details like what representation you want BR, Voxel, Analytic ? making this too vague, non specific, unanswerable other than vague: use CGS engine or procedural voxel map ...

Comment: I want to generate a 3D geometry containing randomly distributed spheres of non-uniform size. The sphere in the box will work as a solid part of its medium, and the space between the two-sphere is pores. The output should be a greyscale 3D image.

Comment: what do you mean by 3D image? Voxel map or 2D image with projected 3D rendered image? (with or without depth map) ? If just what you have on image then that is relatively easy to do ... bin packing ... even simpler is to generate the stuff iteratively by randomly select radius and position outside box and just move the sphere until it hits in predefined direction ... However I do not code in Python/Matlab as i hate those and I am reluctant to answer such questions as my experience is usually waste of my time.

Comment: btw the image clear things up so retracting close vote .... (but still you miss some things I mentioned ...  and many users will not bother with answer without seeing any attempt to solve this on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; since I am starting from scratch with limited knowledge, I needed some reference which I believe I have got. I am working on it and update you soon.